# Aliases defined at login don't seem to work with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I'd like to define some global aliases which would be available for everyone on a mult-user linux system (git shortcuts, etc). It seems I have two options avaialable; either place these aliases in (something like) `/etc/profile.d/aliases_for_all` or editing them into `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

I like the aliases_for_all approach since I can maintain a single file which doesn't breed **.dpkg-*** files like a rabbit after applying updates.

Applying changes to `/etc/bash.bashrc` gets tricky to edit/update at scale -- especially in an environment with multiple distros/versions.

The wrinkle here is that a user can't do a one-shot sudo command using an alias. Given the alias `ds="find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh '\''{}'\'' \;"`, it is available to the initial user login:

```
$ alias | grep ds
alias ds='find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh '\''{}'\'' \;'
```

I change to /var and run it via sudo, but it's not there:

```
$ cd /var
$ sudo ds
sudo: ds: command not found
```

Oh yeah, sudo resets the environment so maybe a login shell:

```
$ sudo --login ds
-bash: ds: command not found
```

Um.. still doesn't work, but alias says it's there:

```
$ sudo --login alias | grep ds
alias ds='find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh '\''{}'\'' \;'
```

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=10
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

..and `/etc/sudoers.d/sysadmin_group` file (LDAP group which user above is in):

```
%sysadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Maybe I've got something else out of whack here. Should there be a way to get these aliases working with sudo?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148545/why-does-sudo-ignore-aliases